# Show content on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="side">
    <h2 class="1">1</h2>
    <h2 class="2">2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="3"href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="4" href="">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What would the code be so when I hover over an `<a>` it will display the `<h2>`?  So `.3` would display `.1`?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#side a").hover( 
            function() { 
                $(this).children('.h2').show(); 
            }, 
            function() { 
                $(this).children('h2').hide(); 
            } 
        ); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
$("#side a").hover(
      function() { $(this).children('.h2').show(); },
      function() { $(this).children('h2').hide(); }
 );

});

        </script>

Comment: I don't know js too well

Comment: Why should it display 1 and not 2?

Comment: @gdoron I believe he is trying to build a menu-type architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example for your test case, you should improve it for your live app.

JSFiddle link: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/RM3yr/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#side h2").hide();
    $("#side ul li a").mouseover(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("3")) {
            $("#side h2.1").show();
        } else if($(this).hasClass("4")) {
            $("#side h2.2").show();
        } 
    }).mouseout(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("3")) {
            $("#side h2.1").hide();
        } else if($(this).hasClass("4")) {
            $("#side h2.2").hide();
        }
    });
})
```

JSFiddle link: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/RM3yr/2/)

Comment: It is pretty static so I do not have to worry about that, I'll keep it in mind. I have this page on save so I can come back if change is needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
.1{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
document.querySelector('.3').onmouseover = function(){
    document.querySelector('.1').style.display = 'block';
};
document.querySelector('.3').onmouseout = function(){
    document.querySelector('.1').style.display = 'none';
};
</script>
<div id="side">
    <h2 class="1">1</h2>
    <h2 class="2">2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="3" href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="4" href="">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Instead of `document.querySelector('.3')` you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('3')[0]`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('.3')` => `document.getElementsByClassName('3')`

Comment: Thank you @gdoron, I forgot removing the dot

Comment: This does not work if you are creating something dynamic. But, +1 (as soon as I got votes again) because pure js is awesome =P

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="side">
    <h2 class="one">What Have You Tried?</h2>
    <h2 class="two">2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="three"href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="four" href="">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#side a").hover( 
            function() { 
                $("#side").find('.one').show(); 
            }, 
            function() { 
                $("#side").find('.one').hide(); 
            } 
        ); 
    }); 
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VdFxf/1/

Comment: @gdoron i thought it is about classes not ids.

Comment: This is gonna show/hide Both **H2** and the question is asking for a specific **h2** in a specific hover from a

Comment: @Michel Ayres yes, it wasn't absolutely baked, adding a class is not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna use `eq()`

If I understood it right, you need your first item from your ul, open the first header. the second item, open the second header, etc.

[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) Get the supplied index that identifies the position of this element in the set.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nymos/xDVcp/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="side">
    <h2 class="1">1</h2>
    <h2 class="2">2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="3" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="4" href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#side a').on('click', function(){
        var index = $('#side a').index(this);
        // alert(index);
        alert($('#side h2').eq(index).html());
    });
});
​
```

NOTE: [Difference between eq and :nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039966/jquery-difference-between-eq-and-nth-child)

---

EIDT: as you ask for hover, you can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#side a').on('hover', function(){
        var index = $('#side a').index(this);
        // alert(index);
        // alert($('#side h2').eq(index).html());
        $('#side h2').eq(index).toggle();
    });
});
```