# Get the value of a div that is append in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and facing a jquery problem.I tried but can't get any idea.
Below is my code,

HTML:

```
 <div class="noti_box1"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
  $(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test</div>");
  $(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test1</div>");
  $(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test2</div>");
  $(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test3</div>");
  $(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test4</div>");
```

Now how can I get the value of 'click' class (third one) using jquery?

The output will be 'Test2'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to select the element at index `n` within the matched set.

```
$(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test1</div>");
$(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test2</div>");
$(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test3</div>");
$(".noti_box1").append("<div class='click'>Test4</div>");

$(".noti_box1 .click:eq(2)").click(function(e){
   alert($(this).text()); //returns "Test3"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on` click function

Try this:

```
$('.click').on('click',function(){
   alert( $(this).text());

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjkueqg7/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use the following:

```
var value = $('.noti_box1 div .click:nth-child(3)').text();
```

edit: I looked it up and it seems that the eq() options posted by others are more efficient.

[jQuery difference between :eq() and :nth-child()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039966/jquery-difference-between-eq-and-nth-child)