# Hide second fieldset in html form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I got a form with the following structure:

```
<form id="user-profile-form" >

 <fieldset> .... </fieldset>

 <fieldset> .... </fieldset>

 <fieldset> .... </fieldset>

 <fieldset> .... </fieldset> 

</form>
```

I am tryingto hide the second fieldset using jquery. I tried the following jquery code to add a class to that fieldset:

```
$('#user-profile-form fieldset:nth-child(2)').addClass('test-class');
```

Also tried below:

```
$('#user-profile-form fieldset:nth-child(2)').hide()
```

I have no access to the form directly, as it is generated somewhere else in code. I just need a jquery script to hide the second fieldset. The `nthchild` should work, but i dont know why, it is not working.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/k2namnfr/

Comment: For me it is not working, Ehsan Sajjad code in his answer worked for me.

Comment: @altafhussain Once again: with information that you have provided it works, as you can see in mentioned fiddle.

Comment: Yes i checked it in fiddle, but i dont know why it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

`$('#user-profile-form fieldset:eq(1)').addClass('test-class');`

### Difference in `:eq` and `:nth-child`:

> > :eq() selects an element based on it's index in the array of selected elements.
> >
> > :nth-child() selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent.

From [**forum.jquery.com**](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/difference-between-nth-child-and-eq):

> > nth-child is 1 indexed while eq is 0 indexed. nth-child is based on the current elements parent, while .eq is based off of the index of the current element relative to the selected elements. they are two completely different methods with two completely different purposes.

Follow this [**link**](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/difference-between-nth-child-and-eq) for better understanding difference between `:nth-child` and `:eq` selector.

You can also refer to this [**SO question : jQuery difference between :eq() and :nth-child()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039966/jquery-difference-between-eq-and-nth-child)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you please explain to me that why nthchild is not working?

Comment: Well, yes, I suspect there are other tags before `<fieldset>`s, so because of _With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class._ there are problems, +1. And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2namnfr/1/) with example.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work, put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ..});` or `$(function(){...});` and try it.

**NOTE** - make sure that your form `id` is unique through out the DOM

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#user-profile-form fieldset:nth-child(2)').addClass('test-class');
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#user-profile-form fieldset:nth-child(2)').hide();
 });
```

Comment: Multiple forms same IDs is the first thing that comes to my mind, +1.

Comment: but Op is using child number not id

Comment: Somehow it was not working. Ehsan Sajjad code worked for me. Yes i was using it as you have described :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad if there are two forms with same ID on the page, it will cause all kind of troubles.

Comment: On the page, there is no duplicate IDs. Also, all the codes above will have problems if there are forms with duplicate IDs.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad sorry for typo in my comment, i dont have any duplidate IDs.

Comment: Yes, but all tags are enclosed in the fieldset tags, input tags, div, span tags etc. But my issue is being fixed.