# :eq pseudo selector not working with Selenium WebDriver / Chrome

Tags: css, ruby, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the first two divs of a given class from a web site using css selectors in selenium.  I'll use SO to demonstrate the problem.  If I try the selector in the console  chrome dev tools it works:

```
$('div.question-summary:eq(0)')
[<div class=​"question-summary narrow tagged-interesting" id=​"question-summary-27442616">​…​</div>​]
$('div.question-summary:eq(1)')
[<div class=​"question-summary narrow tagged-interesting" id=​"question-summary-27442177">​…​</div>​]
```

But if I do the following with selenlium webdriver I get an error:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
first_element = driver.find_element(:css, 'div.mainnav:eq(0)')
```

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Is there another way to express this selector?  Or a way to get selenium to respond to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selenium uses the browser's native CSS selector engine. As a result, the `find_element` method will consider jQuery selectors, in this case the `:eq(0)`, as being invalid.

If you want to use jQuery selectors, you will need to manually execute that script using the `execute_script` method. Note that when using this approach an array of Selenium::WebDriver::Element will be returned, which is why the `.first` is used (to get the first element of the Array).

```
first_element = driver.execute_script('return $("div.question-summary:eq(0)");').first
```

That said, if the only jQuery selector you are trying to use is `:eq`, you could get by with standard CSS selectors. The `:eq` selector returns a specific element within the matching set. You could do the same by using the `find_elements` and `[]` methods:

```
first_element = driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.question-summary')[0]
second_element = driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.question-summary')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a similar result with [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

```
first_element = driver.find_element(:css, 'div.question-summary:nth-child(0)')
```

Just be aware of the [difference between `:eq` and `:nth-child`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040002/1164966)